# Dynamic number of Text output (keep the old one, do not overwrite)

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make a reactive display, that displays a different number of text outputs depending on which value of the input selector is chosen. So, when the user press the Update view button, new output should be executed while the previous output is still visible...

```
{ "outputs" : [ { "var1" :...  , "var2" :.... , "var3" :... , "var4" :.... , "height-weight" :[ 1000 , 500 ]},
{ "var1" :...  , "var2" :.... , "var3" :... , "var4" :.... , "height-weight" :[ 12000 , 34]

,
{ "var1" :...  , "var2" :.... , "var3" :... , "var4" :.... , "height-weight" :[ 12 , 50 ]
```

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("Caption","How many outputs  you want to 
    make?",2,min=1,max=NaN)      ,

    textInput("var1", "var1:"),
   textInput("var2", "var2:" ),
   # Specification of range within an interval
   sliderInput("height", "height:",
              min = -500, max = 500, value = c(1000)),
   sliderInput("weight", "weight:",
              min = -500, max = 500, value = c(500)),

  textInput("var3", "var3" ),
  textInput("var4", "var4" ),


  submitButton("Update View", icon("refresh"))


  # actionButton("update", "Update")

    ),

    mainPanel(


  tableOutput("values"),
  textOutput("text1")


  )
  )
  )
```

server.R

```
    function(input, output,session) {


     # Show the values using an HTML table
    output$values <- renderTable({
    # sliderValues()
    output$text1<- renderText({

      paste("{","\"outputs\"",":","[",
        "{","\"var1\"",":",input$var1,",",
        "\"var2\"",":",input$var2,",",
        "\"feature.attribute\"",":",input$var3,",",
        "\"var3\"",":",input$var4,",",
        "\"var4\"",":",input$var5,",",
        "\"height-weight\"",":","[",input$height,",",input$weight,"]",""




       )
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You want users to input various values, submit those values when they are ready, *then* display submitted values. The following code doesn't solve all your problems, but it should get you started:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel( 
        textInput("var1", "var1:"),
        textInput("var2", "var2:" ),
        # Specification of range within an interval
        sliderInput("height", "height:",
                min = -500, max = 500, value = c(1000)),
        sliderInput("weight", "weight:",
                min = -500, max = 500, value = c(500)),
        textInput("var3", "var3:" ),
        textInput("var4", "var4:" ),
        actionButton("add", "Update View", icon("refresh")),
        tableOutput("values")
        ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
              data <- reactiveValues()
              data$df <- NA
              observeEvent(input$add,
                            { entry <- isolate( data.frame( var1 = input$var1,
                                                            var2 = input$var2,
                                                            var3 = input$var3,
                                                            var4 = input$var4,
                                                            height = input$height,
                                                            weight = input$weight ))
                              isolate(data$df <- rbind(data$df, entry)) })
              output$values <- renderTable({ data$df })
          }

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

*Pay attention to the following commands*

Add new values to existing data is done in shiny with `reactiveValues`. The `data.frame` is stored as an element of `reactiveValues`. To add values only when the user is ready, I use `actionButton` instead of `submitButton`. This lets me `observeEvent` when the action button is pressed. Operations on reactive data are performed through `isolate`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! It was really helpful! I fixed the remaining problem with your help!